# "Can't find 'action.yml'" in reusable workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have below structure:

```
.github
└── workflows
    └── main.yml
    └── send_alerts.yml
```

Now in main, I am using

```
jobs:
  main:
    steps:
      - name: Git Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: some job
        run: |
          ......
  send_alerts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/send_alerts.yml@feature/workflow1
        with:
          provision_status: "Success"
```

in my `send_alerts.yml`

```
name: Creating and Sending Alerts/Status
on:
  workflow_call:
  
    provision_status:
      required: true
      type: string

jobs:
  create_send_alerts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Git Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Some other jobs
        run: |
        .....
```

so this thorws me error:

```
Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/git-repo/.github/workflows/send_alerts.yml@feature/workflow1'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

So my question is why it is complaining about action in `send_alerts` for main? while in the main.yml same `actions/checkout@v3` works just fine?

I tried both actions/checkout@v2 and v3 in all cases I have same error

Answer (score 6):

There are at least three things wrong:

1. You're calling a reusable workflow like an action. The call to a reusable workflow replaces the entire job, not just one step.
2. When you reference a workflow (or an action) that's in the same repository, with a relative path, you must not add an `@version` suffix. If you look at the error message, the runner is interpreting that as a directory name.

Both together result in something like this:

```yaml
  send_alerts:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/send_alerts.yml
    with:
      provision_status: "Success"
```

3. You have to declare the parameter in an `inputs` object in the reusable workflow:

   ```yaml
   on:
     workflow_call:
       inputs:
         provision_status:
           required: true
           type: string
   ```

Comment: I run in the same issue and I wonder why the runner is interpreting that as a directory name and how to solve this.

Comment: Got it. I my case I had also steps configured within the job that should reuse another workflow. But there only `uses: ..`must be configured like in the answer here.